# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Projecting Touch Position

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, touch-event

Im new to OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android and I want to make simple application to train my skills. I have a problem  with projecting positions. I draw some squares in my apps, and I want to detect which square I hit while touching screen. If I dont use Model-View-Projection Matrix, everything is easy, but when I use MVP Matrix I just dont understand how it works. Here's some code:
in AngelicRenderer class:

```
    @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused)
        {
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            // Set the camera position (View matrix)
            Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 3f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);

            // Calculate the projection and view transformation
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

            lock.lock();
            try
            {
                for(Entry> squares : getObjects())
                {
                    for(AngelicSquare square : squares.getValue())
                    {
                        square.draw(mMVPMatrix);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height)
        {
            GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

            float ratio = (float) width / height;
            screenWidth = width;
            screenHeight = height;

            // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
            // in the onDrawFrame() method
            Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1f, 1f, 1f, 10f);
        }
```

in AngelicView class, onTouchEvent:

```
    for(Entry> squares : devilishRenderer.getObjects())
    {
        for(AngelicSquare square : squares.getValue())
        {
            float[] coords = square.getPosition();
            float[] size = square.getSize();
            float[] touchPoint = { e.getX(), e.getY(), 0.0f, 0.0f };
            float[] touchPointNew = ViewCoordsToGLCoords(touchPoint);
            float[] topLeft = { coords[0], coords[1], 0.0f, 0.0f };
            Matrix.multiplyMV(topLeft, 0, devilishRenderer.getMVPMatrix(), 0, topLeft, 0);
            float[] bottomRight = { coords[0] + size[0], coords[1] - size[1], 0.0f, 0.0f };
            Matrix.multiplyMV(bottomRight, 0, devilishRenderer.getMVPMatrix(), 0, bottomRight, 0);
            Matrix.multiplyMV(touchPoint, 0, devilishRenderer.getMVPMatrix(), 0, touchPointNew, 0);

            if(touchPoint[0] > topLeft[0] && touchPoint[1]  bottomRight[1])
            {
                hookedSquare = square;
            }
        }
    }
```

How I can project screens coordinations to OpenGL coordination system with Model-View-Projection Matrix?